# Calculated column needs to be created based on two existing columns dimensions in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 columns in my data set Column A and Column B. I need to create a calculated column based on the combination of Column A and Column B. In a normal scenario, a nested IF statement will be enough.

But in real-time I have 5 distinct values in Column A and around 70 distinct values in Column B and there are around 140+ combinations of both the column data in the data set. The user has provided the mapping for these 140+ combinations.

I somehow managed to manually input all the combinations in a nested IF statement but that is not feasible and it may have a lot of errors and is hard to maintain.

Need help to simplify this and assign it to the calculated column output. Kindly suggest the best way to do it.

[image: Sample DataSet for reference:]

Comment: How you are calculating `Derived Column` in your table, is it some sort of calculation or it is just a concatenation? And how do you define your `Set 1`, `Set 2`, and `Set 3`?

Comment: Hi, For each unique set of Column A & Column B values i am creating an IF statement and iterating the next one in the FALSE condition. My current code has more than 140 lines with all the specified conditions.